# Problems After Deploying Gitub Repo to Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I created an AKS successfully and tried to deploy a project from my Github repository. I followed the guidance on the following page and it sent me a success notice in the Azure Portal.

[image: The Deployment Center After Deplying My Github Repo]

However, later I found some hidden failure notice on Azure that lead me to a typo in the Dockerfile (`MAINTANER` vs `MAINTAINER`). I fixed the typo, and cleared the `workflow` directory and some other stuff automatically created by Azure that now I don't remember. Then I used the Action panel in Github repo to re-run the task but failed:

[image]

The log shows that it's still running with the old command with typo (`MAINTANER`). Why did this happen?

---

There was a second question here. I deleted the second question since it's distracting and already answered by @Nick.

Comment: am I right that you have fixed (commited and pushed) the typo for the Master branch and you are using exactly Master branch for a workflow (trying to avoid situation when the fix was for some other branch)

Comment: @Nick Hi! I have successfully passed the "build and push image to ACR" step. Actually, before this, I even produced my image locally, ran a container by that image locally, and was able to access my APIs from that local container. The whole deployment process to the cloud is also finished with no problem. However, I can't access the container cluster on the cloud.

Comment: Hello @Yan, that looks like a valid reason for creating a new question instead of reopening this one

Answer (score 1):

I see, that you have Security rules created and wondering why you can not ping the public IP.

The root of the issue is that ICMP traffic is not allowed. That is the reason why you can't ping your host.

On your last screenshot "Any" is referring to the protocols for "port 22" only. And pings aren't sent on port 22.

Please create an Inbound rule for "ICMP" only (and you'll see that the "Destination port ranges" field is populated with asterisk upon selecting "ICMP") so you'll be able to ping the host.

Hope that helps.